# Angular js ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have done a sample app with angular js and added a `ng-repeat` to loop my data but it's not looping it. I have shown my code below

```
 <li style="background: white url('{{book.imgUrl}}') no-repeat" ng-repeat="book in books">
          <div>
            <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{book.price}}</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
              <li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
              <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
              <li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
            </ul>
            <p>{{book.details}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
          </div>
        </li>
```

I have created a live demo of the problem [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rwb1BLmeClGFrbtwS3Ua/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get value in view from controller , you have to bind that with $scope.

Your books variable isn't bind with scope

Convert this

```
var books=[
```

to this

```
$scope.books=[
```

or like this

```
$scope.books=books
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/4HDtkRfQ0NAL6ILloToW?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use `$scope.books` instead of `var books = [];`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, instead of using

```
var books
```

use

```
$scope.books
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

Instead of `var book` you need to glue book variable with $scope

Like

```
 $scope.book=[{

   // Rest of code
}]
```

Also first pass the dependency as string else you may see error during minification

```
    app.controller('BookListCtrl',["$scope", function($scope) {
   // Rest of code

}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$scope.books` instead of var books.

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/rwb1BLmeClGFrbtwS3Ua?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Assign your book in specific controller scope object parameter as per below

```
app.controller('BookListCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.books=books;
})
```

Comment: Nikhil, its Working